# Google Video Intelligence AutoML inference

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I've trained a model using Google's AutoML Video Intelligence and now trying to make predictions on a video of just 2 seconds using nodejs client's batch prediction but the inference time is no where near production grade, it's taking almost like a minute to make prediction on just 2 seconds of video. Am I missing some setting here or it's the way it is right now?

Answer (score 0):

Some findings on this issue:

- Try to follow [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/docs/best-practices) and see how  to  [improve model performance](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/docs/best-practices#improving_model_performance)
- I have found another [latency issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cloud-videointel-discuss/B2dkVlkHGnk/GiytxcQnCAAJ) in google groups for auto ml, it suggests that If you're putting the base64-encoded bytes directly in 'inputContent' you might want to consider uploading the input_video file directly to Google Cloud Storage and using 'inputUri' instead of ‘inputContent.’ This will reduce the request payload size and the upload-latency.
- This might be caused by a [quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/quotas), you can confirm in the logs (by job id) for quota errors
- Finally, you can open an issue at the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) with a  sample video and command for issue reproduction and further investigation.

Good luck!

Comment: @Isaab I'm using google cloud storage i.e. bucket and providing uri to video in bucket but even then the inference is taking so much time. Google is charging a certain amount on batch inference as well.

Comment: If you don't see any errors in your logs related to quotas, please create a AutoML issue in the [public tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports)